# JavaScript Promises not waiting for for loop to finish execute

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I was having some problem with promises in JavaScript. What I trying to do is I will get a list of items based on category, then loop thru that list to get the item details based in item ID.

```
get(category).then((list) => {
        let key = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            for(var i = 0; i <list.length; i++){
                // logic
                });
            }
            resolve(list);
            console.log(list);
        });

        key.then((list) => {});
});
```

The problem now is the code above will execute the resolve without waiting for the for loop to finish looping. This resulting in an empty ritemlist which affect my code logic in the promiseKey.then().

The correct sequence will be for loop finish to complete populating ritemlist then resolve and then the promise.then().

Thanks!

Comment: That’s one incredibly long name for a function

Comment: why would anything wait for the for loop to finish? you need to wait for `all` the `promise`s returned by `getReceiptItemByID`

Comment: @JaromandaX Any ideas to fix this? Because the strange part is the code above works for one project. But then when I tried to separate out some portion into another project, it just break.

Comment: `getAllReceiptItemIDByCategory(category).then(ritemIDlist => Promise.all(ritemIDlist.map(ritemID => getReceiptItemByID(ritemID.receiptItemID))));`

Comment: What makes you think the for loop didn't finish looping?

Comment: `the code above works for one project` I highly doubt it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Promises are not blocking.  So, the loop just runs to completion, long before the promises are done.  In other words, nothing in your code waits for the promises inside the loop.  Instead, you can accumulate a list of promises into an array (using `.map()`) and then use `Promise.all()` to know when they are all done:

```
getAllReceiptItemIDByCategory(category).then((ritemIDlist) => {
        // get all related receipt item details
        return Promise.all(ritemIDList.map(ritem => {
            return getReceiptItemByID(ritem.receiptItemID);
        })).then(receipts => {
            console.log(receipts);
            return receipts;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;
        });
});
```

The `.then()` and `.catch()` handlers shown here are optional and are only here to log the result locally.  They can be omitted if the caller is processing the result or error and you don't need/wait local logging.

In addition, please avoid the [promise executor anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) where you wrap an existing promise with another manually created promise.  There is never a reason to do that.  Instead, you can just use or return the inner promise and do not need to wrap it again.